# Input Validation in React Components

Tags: reactjs, validation

Now, I'm working with React and faced one issue.
Added validation, it doesn't work. My code is as follows.

```
 <TextField
    margin="dense"
    id="email"
    label="Email"
    type="input"
    fullWidth
    {...register("email", {
       required: true,
       pattern: {
       value: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
       message: "Entered value does not match email format",
     },
    })}
   value={userData.email}
   onChange={(e) =>
      setUserData({ ...userData, email: e.target.value })
    }
  />
```

Declaration below;

```
 const {
            register,
        } = useForm<IUserData>();
    
    export declare interface IUserData {
        id?: number;
        userName?: string;
        email?: string;
        realName?: string;
        phone?: string;
        status?: boolean;
        role?: number;
        emailVerified?: boolean;
        phoneVerified?: boolean;
    };
```

Is there any good way to implement validation?

Comment: What have you done to try and fix it?

Comment: ..what doesn't work? Traceback info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation write correct but you incorrect call `setUserData`, try like that

```
onChange={(e) =>
   setUserData(prev => { 
       return {
         ...prev,
         email: e.target.value
    }})
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sky-setcg)

Comment: Sorry, it doen't work Mr Rayets.

Comment: What error or what behavior ?

Comment: See example all is work https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sky-setcg

Comment: If you want validate dynamic just do `setValue` on change event

Comment: Mr. Rayets, Thank you very much.

Comment: If it helped, mark answer as accepted